# How to avoid collection modification during JSON serialization in looped multithreaded task?

Tags: c#, json.net, task, jsonserializer

I have a problem during serialization to JSON file, when using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

In a loop I am fiering tasks in various threads:

```
List<Task> jockeysTasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 1100; i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    LoadedJockey jockey = new LoadedJockey();
                    jockey = await Task.Run(() => _scrapServices.ScrapSingleJockeyPL(j));

                    if (jockey.Name != null)
                    {
                        _allJockeys.Add(jockey);
                    }

                    UpdateStatusBar = j * 100 / 1100;

                    if (j % 100 == 0)
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => _dataServices.SaveAllJockeys(_allJockeys)); //saves everything to JSON file
                    }
                });

                jockeysTasks.Add(task);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(jockeysTasks);
```

And `if (j % 100 == 0)`, it is rying to save the collection `_allJockeys` to the file (I will make some counter to make it more reliable, but that is not the point):

```
public void SaveAllJockeys(List<LoadedJockey> allJockeys)
        {
            if (allJockeys.Count != 0)
            {
                if (File.Exists(_jockeysFileName)) File.Delete(_jockeysFileName);

                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(_jockeysFileName))
                    {
                        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                        serializer.Serialize(file, allJockeys);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    dialog.ShowDialog("Could not save the results, " + e.ToString(), "Error");
                }
            }
        }
```

During that time, as I belive, another tasks are adding new collection item to the collection, and it is throwing to me the exception:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

As I was reading in [THE ARTICLE](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/02/28/enumerating-collections-that-change-in-csharp/), you can change type of iteration to avoid an exception. As far as I know, I can not modify the way, how `Newtonsoft.Json` pack is doing it.

Thank you in advance for any tips how to avoid the exception and save the collection wihout unexpected changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tied to use `ToList()` on the collection, what creates copy of the list, with positive effect.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably inherit from List and use a ReaderWriterLock (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=netframework-4.8)

i.e. (not tested pseudo C#)

```
public class MyJockeys: List<LoadedJockey>
{

    System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock _rw_lock = new System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock();

    public new Add(LoadedJockey j)
    {
       try
       {
           _rw_lock.AcquireWriterLock(5000); // or whatever you deem an acceptable timeout
          base.Add(j);
       }
       finally
       {
           _rw_lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
       }
    }

    public ToJSON()
    {
       try
       {
           _rw_lock.AcquireReaderLock(5000); // or whatever you deem an acceptable timeout
          string s = "";  // Serialize here using Newtonsoft
          return s;
       }
       finally
       {
           _rw_lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
       }
    }
    // And override Remove and anything else you need
}
```

Get the idea?

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Adam.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found a bit simpler solution. I tyed to use `ToList()` on the collection, what creates copy of the list, with positive effect.

Comment: Good to hear. Glad you're sorted :-)